# Delayed variable initialization

Tags: scala, initialization

Let's say I have a variable which I cannot initialize immediately, because I do not know its value (so `lazy val` won't work for me). I also cannot control the moment the object creation because it is handled by a framework (e.g. `Activity` in an Android app), so I cannot delay creation of whole object. I do NOT want to use `var` for this, as it brings the risk of incomplete initialization and invalid states.

So far I've been using approach like:

```
class MyClass extends InterfaceWithDelayedInitialization {

  private val delayedValueP = Promise[Type]()
  private val delayedValueF = delayedValueP.future

  def onCreate(value: Type): Unit = {
    delayedValueP.successful(value)
  }

  def someOtherMethod(): Unit = {
    delayedValueF foreach { value =>
      // do something with value
    }
  }
}
```

but I cannot help but feel that this approach is kind of smelly (not as smelly as using mutability and `var`s though).

Is there some standard solution for a problems like this one?

Comment: `InterfaceWithDelatedInitialization` or `InterfaceWithDelayedInitialization`?

Comment: Do you know about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html ?

Comment: I think I'm missing the point, delaying the initialization of a variable smells already like you are mutating things and "waiting" for something to happen, if you need this variable to be recalculated you could simply use a method, but I'm guessing your use case is more complicated than that.

Comment: I am doing some experiments with Scala and Android and there I have classes instantiated by the framework/environment, which at some point calls `onCreate`. Only then I can calculate the value and set it. After that it won't ever be changed. I wanted to distill that use case as I met exactly the same problem in some other project I worked on. Point is I don't want  an object with `var`s that are `null` for some time and instead I want some way to deal with the problem as cleanly as possible.